# PostgreSQL: How do I setup a local server / client environment for initial database experimentation

Tags: postgresql, server

I've recently decided to embark on a fun / educational personal project to create some data visualizations and power metrics for my fantasy football league.  Since ESPN doesn't provide an API, I've decided to use a combination of elbow grease and the [nfldb](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki) to pull relevant data (and am hoping to get familiar with Plotly for presenting the data).  In setting up `nfldb`, I'm also getting my first exposure to databases, using postgresql in particular ([as required by `nfldb`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Installation)).

Since the installation guide provided by nfldb is Linux-centric and assumes a fair bit of previous database experience, I've looked to [this guide](http://nflwin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nfldb.html) for help and blindly followed its instructions in hopes of sidestepping postgresql (aka the "just make it work" "solution").  Of course, that didn't work, and I have no idea how to diagnose the problem(s), so I've decided to go ahead and use this opportunity to get a little familiar with databases / postgresql.

I've looked to the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) for guidance.  Having never worked in a server / client environment, the following text (from "18.1. The PostgreSQL User Account") has me particularly confused:

```
As with any server daemon that is accessible to the outside world, it is advisable
to run PostgreSQL under a separate user account. This user account should only own
the data that is managed by the server, and should not be shared with other
daemons. (For example, using the user nobody is a bad idea.) It is not advisable
to install executables owned by this user because compromised systems could then
modify their own binaries.

To add a Unix user account to your system, look for a command useradd or adduser.
The user name postgres is often used, and is assumed throughout this book, but you
can use another name if you like.
```

I'd really appreciate a well annotated version of these paragraphs.  How does it apply to someone like me, storing and accessing date on the same machine?  Do I need to create a new system user account?  How do I make sure it "only owns the data that is managed by the server"?  Where is the responsible location to install postgresql?  Am I exposed to some sort of security risk by downloading the `nfldb` database?  Why is the user `nobody` a bad idea?

Relevant:  I am using a Mac (v10.11.6) and plan to install (or re-install, if necessary) postgresql using Homebrew.

Comment: Personally, I'd just go sign up for a free account with Amazon AWS and use an RDS instance, You're up and running with a couple of clicks inside 30 minutes easy. Then download pgadmin and connect to it. Make sure it's publicly accessible. The cool thing is if you screw something up, just start over.

Comment: Normally, the *administrative account* `postgres` is the "owner" of both the executables and the data. The stanard installation procedure will probably create a `postgres` account, if it does not exist already. Note: most of the Postgres development team works on Macs, so that should not be a problem. (and user `nobody` is a bad idea, IMHO)